# Insert each selected checkbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying insert as string each selected checkbox, Name value.

Here is my code:

```
Connection.Extras =  mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ExtrasName);
```

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string' 
Connection is my class and extras is a public static string Extras

Comment: this is not JAVA.

Comment: what type is Connection.Extras and what is your expected output

Comment: Lets say that i want to use string name; and put my output there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
  mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ExtrasName)
```

returns list of strings (`List<string>`) which you are trying to write into `string` variable. You can convert it to comma separated values (as one approach) like this:

```
Connection.Extras = 
string.Join(", ", mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ExtrasName).ToArray());
```

Comment: Just one question! How much study someone's need for achieve something like that! I'm trying to find atleast one week! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Another off-topic question is it possible to sum selected??Example "ExtrasPrice"

Comment: `mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Sum(x => x.ExtrasPrice)`? :)

Comment: Thank you sir it works once again! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!! I just needed to convert it as demical!  Connection.Extras = string.Join(". ", mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ExtrasPrice)));

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<string> list=(mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ExtrasName.ToString())).ToList();
Connection.Extras =  string joined = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: okay. can you explain what "Connection.Extras" is in your code is?

Comment: I just tried it but now i take this error: 
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'.

Comment: It works but it gives me only first selected text. I want to take each selected with a comma after it

Comment: No i want each result for my selected checkboxes! Thank you sir you helped me so much!